# How to exclude an element from being dragged in sortable list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

How can I exclude an element from sortable list? For instance, there is an element with class name 'note' that I **don't** want to be **draggable**?

```
    <ul class="sortable">

            <li id="item_3">Item 3</li>
            <li id="item_4">Item 4</li>
            <li id="item_5">Item 5</li>

            <p class="note">This is a note only</p> 
   </ul>
```

jquery ui sortable, jquery `not` obviously does not work...

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable:not(.note)" ).sortable(
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to use cancel.

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/9KkWn/2/).

Js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.sortable').sortable();
    $('.sortable').disableSelection();
    $('.sortable').sortable({ cancel: '.note' });
});​
```

As @Zephyr points out, this let's you re-arrange the position by dragging the siblings, if you want to avoid that, use [owise1 approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17710365/463065):

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    items : ':not(.note)'
});
```

Comment: Careful: this solution will indeed prevent the item to be draggable, but it will still be possible to move sibling draggable elements around it.

Comment: In my case only using `":not(.any-class)"` broke the sortable-behaviour since the selector was too general and applied to descendant DOM elements. I used `"> :not(.any-class)"` to fix this as the default value for _items_ is `"> *"`. [Sortable Widget: items](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items)

Answer (score 24):

You could use sortable's "[items](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items)" option:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    items : 'li'
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/owise1/kK5ky/)

or...

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    items : ':not(.note)'
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/owise1/T7FmK/)

Comment: This also works with `<tr>` tags containing a dataset: `$("#table").sortable({items: "[data-real-line]"});`.

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly exclude items with:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
     cancel: ".disable-sorting"
});
```