# Stop siblings replacing order of canceled element with jQuery-ui

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

## What I'm trying to do

I'm using the jQuery-ui to sort a number of sections of html. So far the items are sortable. I want to disable sorting for two divs and keep the sortable functionality on the others.

I'm working within a CMS that has already declared these sections as sortable. What I'm trying to do is force the elements with a class of `"not-sortable"` to not be sortable.

*Simplified example*

#### HTML

```
<div class="normal-sortables">
    <div class"not-sortable">Not sortable section</div>
    <div class"not-sortable">Not sortable section</div>
    <div>Sortable section</div>
    <div>Sortable section</div>
</div>
```

#### JQUERY

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#normal-sortables").sortable({
        cancel:".not-sortable"
    });
});
```

This prevents the "not-sortable" items from being dragagable, but if you move the siblings above these sections, they still move and their order is changed.

I found [this question 13885665](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885665/sortable-and-draggable-how-to-exclude-an-element-from-sortable-list-being-dragg/17710365#17710365)

So, I changed my solution above to

```
$( "#normal-sortables" ).sortable({
    items : ':not(.not-sortable)'
});
```

This disabled all items.

I'm not experienced with jQuery, I found much more complex solutions to my problem but I'd like to understand why the above isn't working and to keep things simple if possible.

It seems like I must be missing something obvious.

### UPDATE

The code above does work, but my situation is more complicated. Therefore I've posted a new more specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696012/is-it-possible-to-override-defined-options-of-the-jquery-ui-sortable-widget)

I'll keep this post updated with results too to keep things linked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just had a typo or if something else happened, but `items : ':not(.not-sortable)'` seems to work.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".normal-sortables").sortable({
    items: ":not(.not-sortable)"
  });

  $('.normal-sortables').disableSelection(); // added for example only
  
});
```

```css
.normal-sortables div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="normal-sortables">
  <div class="not-sortable">Not sortable section</div>
  <div class="not-sortable">Not sortable section</div>
  <div>Sortable section</div>
  <div>Sortable section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in and confirming that @apaul34208. Yes, it seems as though my question is more detailed than I first thought and therefore it's better that I ask a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696012/is-it-possible-to-override-defined-options-of-the-jquery-ui-sortable-widget