# jquery soratble: how to Completely exclude an element from being sorted

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

It may seem like this question has been asked and answered multliple times but it won't work for me.
    [How to exclude an element from being dragged in sortable list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885665/sortable-and-draggable-how-to-exclude-an-element-from-sortable-list-being-dragg)

The solution described here indeed prevents the row form being clicked and dragged but it won't prevent other elements from being dragged around it.
I want the last row in the table to stay where it is no matter what. I don't want the user to be able to drag it nor do I want the user to be able drag other rows past it.
The structure needs to look as follows:

```
<table ui:sortable>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      <tr>
       ..
      <tr>
      <tr>   -----this row needs to stay
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `but it won't prevent other elements from being dragged around it`, so you wan't nothing in the list to be sortable? Please provide more context.

Comment: It sounds like you need multiple sortable elements, something like http://jsfiddle.net/nbLeba3t/

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is this:

```
<table class="sortable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
         ..
        <tr>
        <tr>   
        <tr>-----this row needs to stay
    </tbody>
</table>


$(function() {
    $last = $(".sortable tr").last();
    $( ".sortable").sortable({
      items: "tr",
      cancel: "tr:last-child",
      update: function(event, ui) {
          $last.appendTo(".sortable");
      }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nbLeba3t/8/

Comment: Thanks but your example has "ui:sortable" at tbody not at the table element. For reasons I won't get into here ui:sortable needs to be at the table element.

Comment: `$( ".sortable tbody").sortable();` can't you just do that, in this case? http://jsfiddle.net/nbLeba3t/2/

Comment: It is a completely valid solution and if I was starting fresh I'd definitely try that. However I'm dealing existing legacy code that has the table structure matching the controller. The controller code relies on the sticky row being exactly a <tr> entry in the table body. The code is fairly complex and I didn't write it and I'd rather not touch it at this point.

Comment: See edit, basically after they drag you just take what was originally the last item, and stick it back at the end.

Comment: Upvoted your answer, need to run now, will try implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the sortable items to be of a certain class, or like in code snippet below, to everything but of a certain class.

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable").sortable({
      items: "tr:not(.footer)"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table class="sortable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="footer">
            <td>I'm a fixed footer</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You could even make it work without having any class using the `:last` selector:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable").sortable({
      items: "tr:not(:last)"
    });
});
```