# how to remove sorting from a certain table column jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new to jquery and I'm not a programer either.
I've tried searching for the answer on google but I just couldn't find the answer.

I have created a table and applied sorting in columns but **i dont want to make few columns sortable which has class named ".canvas-head"**. 
This is what i am trying:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('#sorting').sorttable({
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    helperCells: ':not(.footerrow td)'
}).disableSelection();

  function reset(){
     $(".canvas-head").sorttable('disable');
   }
   $('.canvas-head').bind('click',reset);
});
</script>

<table id="sorting">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="headerrow ui-sortable">
                    <th class="ui-resizable tac"><div class="ui-resizable">First Year Corn <br>Non Limited N, High Pop(1)</div></th>
                  <th class="canvas-head">Canvas</th>
                    <th class="ui-resizable tac"><div class="ui-resizable">First Year Corn <br>Non Limited N, High Pop(2)</div></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
<td>one</td>
<td>Two</td>
<td>three</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPrbNQ)

Comment: `sorttable`..? really..? Please take sometime, proof read your question and check whether the code works without obvious syntax errors before posting questions...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude an element from sortable list being dragged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885665/how-to-exclude-an-element-from-sortable-list-being-dragged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
items: "td:not(.canvas-head)"
```

Take a look here : [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/68bd6q38/)

reference link : [jquery ui sortable disable for one li item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370754/jquery-ui-sortable-disable-for-one-li-item)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a **class** or **id** for the certain table columns for which you dont want to apply `sortable` and than you can use `.not` in selection

**For Eg:**

```
$(function() {
      $('#list').sortable({items: '> li:not(.pin)'});
});

<ul id="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li class="pin">Five</li>
</ul>
```