# How can I disable sort on a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sortablejs

I'm having difficulty disabling sorting on a specific `li` in my `ul`.
I'm using [SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable).

```
<ul id="items">
    <li class="static">
        <div class="image"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="text">Static</div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="text">Dynamic</div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="image"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="text">Dynamic</div>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

One `li` with class `static` should NOT be sortable. The others should be sortable.

```
var el = document.getElementById('items');

var sortable = new Sortable(el, {
    onUpdate: function (evt) {
        var itemEl = evt.item;

        // here happens some stuff
    },
    filter: '.js-remove',
    onFilter: function (evt) {
        // here happens some stuff
    }
});
```

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13885829/673991) you can do it in [jQuery UI sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) like this:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    cancel: ".static"
});
```

How can I do this in SortableJS?

Comment: So you are or you are not using jQuery UI sortable?

Comment: @epascarello, no I'm sorry. I removed the tag.

Comment: what happens when you try it? can we have a jsfiddle?

Comment: its the `filter` option = `filter: '.static',`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Further to @BenG comment, you need to use [`filter`](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#options) instead of `cancel`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('items');
var sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
   filter: ".static"
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.4.2/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/st/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="items" class="block__list block__list_words">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li class="static">item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `filter` option disables **dragging**. But the element can still be rearranged by dropping a different element on top of it. To disable **dropping**. you need [the technique](https://jsbin.com/voroqedeqo/edit?html,js,output) of checking the `related` property in an `onMove` event handler:  `onMove: function (e) { return e.related.className.indexOf('static') === -1;  }`  (This answer does fulfill the original question, but just to augment it a bit for a closely related issue. For posterity.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add two options when creating the sortable instance:

```
    var container = document.getElementById('my-list');
    var sortable = Sortable.create(container, {
       // 1.) Exclude all elements having class '.static' from being draggable.
       draggable: 'li:not(.static)',
       // 2.) Prevent all elements having class '.static' from being moved.
       onMove(e) {
         return e.related.className.indexOf('static') === -1;          
       }
    });
```

**Why should I not use `filter` option**?

Looking at the accepted answer, it seems like the `filter` option would do the job. But whenever you use multiple instances with interchangeable elements, it becomes problematic if one of the lists get empty. Suddenly you won't be able to add elements to that list again. This is due to Sortable's internal logic, which still treats the `.static` element as a draggable element. Even setting the `emptyInsertThreshold` option to be really high won't fix that, because for Sortable, the list is *not* empty.

**Example 1 using `filter` option:** (Try to add 'Apple' to COMPANIES - it won't work!)

```js
var el = document.getElementById('items');
var sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
   draggable: 'li:not(.static)',
   group: {
     name: 'list'
   },
   onMove(e) {
     return e.related.className.indexOf('static') === -1;          
   }
});
var items2 = document.getElementById('items2');
var sortable = Sortable.create(items2, {
   filter: '.static',
   group: {
     name: 'list'
   },
   onMove(e) {
     return e.related.className.indexOf('static') === -1;          
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.14.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<ul id="items">
    <li class="static">FRUITS</li>
    <li>Strawberry</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Peach</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
</ul><ul id="items2">
    <li class="static">COMPANIES</li>
</ul>
```

**Example 2 using `draggable` option:** (Try to add 'Apple' to COMPANIES - it works!)

```js
var el = document.getElementById('items');
var sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
   draggable: 'li:not(.static)',
   group: {
     name: 'list'
   },
   onMove(e) {
     return e.related.className.indexOf('static') === -1;          
   }
});
var items2 = document.getElementById('items2');
var sortable = Sortable.create(items2, {
   draggable: 'li:not(.static)',
   group: {
     name: 'list'
   },
   onMove(e) {
     return e.related.className.indexOf('static') === -1;          
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.14.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<ul id="items">
    <li class="static">FRUITS</li>
    <li>Strawberry</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Peach</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
</ul><ul id="items2">
    <li class="static">COMPANIES</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works nice, but when there are no elements in the group one cant move elemnts from other group to it

Comment: @Jan Thank's for pointing that out! I updated my answer, seems like`filter` is not the best way to make it work.